# Adobe AEM DAM is asset meta data accessible on the publish server

Tags: adobe, aem, dam

Is the metadata for Adobe AEM DAM assets accessible on Publish servers, or only on Author servers?

Comment: There are many ways to check this. Have you tried anything ?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, when you activate it, it will activate the node along with the relevant meta data.

Try referencing a URL like this on both author and publisher to compare:

```
/content/dam/yourDirectory/yourDamAssety.jpg/jcr:content.infinity.json
```

By accessing `.infinity.json` you can see the attributes of a node. Specifically, there is a `metadata` child node under `jcr:content` that has the attributes you are likely interested in.